# Play Scala changing custom List item value

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, scala-collections, typesafe-activator

In my `Play Framework Scala` project I have a `custom List`.Some operations I need to change/replace the custom List Item value with `another value`.`Scala` doesn't have a methods which `Java` has like below

```
List<Int> testList = new ArrayList<Int>();
testList.get(0)// get the testList 0 th value
```

**What I need**

```
case class ImageGrid(
    image_id: Int,
    image_name: String,    
    image_desc: String   
    )

val ImageGridList:List[ImageGrid] = //based on some DB Query I set values
```

How Can I change/Replace the `0th` or `1st` position of `ImageGridList's` `image_name` or   `image_desc`

Comment: Scala does have a `List.get`, it's called `apply` you can just do `scalaList(0)`.  In any case, what have you tried to actually implement  your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer instead of List

```
val list = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(1,2,3,4)
```

Set value at position by index:

```
list(0)=5
```

Comment: could you please explain with some code snippets ? It will be useful

Comment: Okay fine.is it possible to change `List[ImageGrid]` into `ArrayBuffer[ImageGrid]`

Comment: You can use method appendAll of ArrayBuffer

Answer (score 1):

You can use ArrayBuffer which is mutable, here is an example code;

```
scala> import scala.collection._
 import scala.collection._

 scala> case class ImageGrid(
   |     image_id: Int,
   |     image_name: String,    
   |     image_desc: String   
   |     )
defined class ImageGrid

scala> val imageGridList = mutable.Buffer[ImageGrid](ImageGrid(1,"img1","img2"))
imageGridList: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[ImageGrid] = ArrayBuffer(ImageGrid(1,img1,img2))

scala> imageGridList(0) = ImageGrid(1,"img name changed","img2")

scala> imageGridList
res1: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[ImageGrid] = ArrayBuffer(ImageGrid(1,img name changed,img2))
```

To convert existing List to ArrayBuffer use `toBuffer`

Comment: I already done a needed process for getting a `List[ImageGrid]` so How can I convert `List[ImageGrid]` into `ArrayBuffer[ImageGrid]`